# pulseaudio: how to set the "configured latency" of a module-tunnel-sink-new

Tags: pulse-audio

I have a setup at home with a local pulseaudio (the movie player) connecting through module-tunnel-sink-new to a remote pulseaudio server (the speaker). I'd like to lower the latency of this tunnel (in order to combine multiple sinks but that's besides the point).

Indeed, this latency seems configurable since when i list the sinks i can see that it is set by default at 200000 usec: 

`Latency: 182906 usec, configured 200000 usec`

I looked through the options of module-tunnel-sink-new but I can't seem to find where to configure it (remember, this is a tunnel, not an actual card).